# How to remove an item from List<>?

Tags: java, android, list, arraylist

I'm developing an app, which contains a list of tickets, there are add ticket and remove ticket options for the user. The add option works fine, but the remove option doesn't, here is the ticket list code

```
public class TicketList {

    private List<Ticket> ticketList;

    public TicketList() {
        ticketList = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public List<Ticket> getTicketList() {
        return ticketList;
    }

    public void setTicketList(List<Ticket> ticketList) {
        this.ticketList = ticketList;
    }

    public void addTicketToList(Ticket ticket) {
        ticketList.add(ticket);
    }

    public void removeFromList(Ticket ticket) {
        ticketList.remove(ticket);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "TicketList{" + "ticketList=" + ticketList + '}';
    }
}
```

The delete function in another activity which doesn't work:

```
private void deleteTicket() {
    TicketList ticketList = MyPreferencesManager.getInstance(this).getTicketList();
    Ticket ticket = MyPreferencesManager.getInstance(this).getTicket();
    ticketList.removeFromList(ticket);
    MyPreferencesManager.getInstance(this).putTicketList(ticketList);
}
```

While the add function works fine:

```
private void saveTicket() {
    TicketList ticketList = MyPreferencesManager.getInstance(this).getTicketList();
    Ticket ticket = new Ticket();
    ticket.setUsername(username.getText().toString());
    ticket.setPassword(password.getText().toString());
    ticketList.addTicketToList(ticket);
    MyPreferencesManager.getInstance(this).putTicketList(ticketList);
}
```

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with the deleting or removing function?

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work"? Does nothing happen? Does it crash? Also see if the ticket in question is even in the list. You might have to override the `equals` and the `hashCode` function of your `Ticket` class for it to work.

Comment: nah , i mean , nothing happens , to make it more clear , when i get log before and after add , i can see the result in logcat , but for removing item, nothing changes after calling the delete function

Comment: If you don't have an `equals` method defined in your `Ticket` class, Java can only compare the tickets by reference, and not by value, which will lead to errors in matching the correct Object from the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because when you're using the following code:

```
ticketList.remove(ticket);
```

the remove method will check if there is an **exact object item** in the list before removing. So, your ticket object probably is already changed before you're trying to delete it from the list.

You can see the details from [List documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/List.html#remove(java.lang.Object)):

> public abstract boolean remove (Object o)
>
> Removes the first occurrence of the specified element from this list,
>   if it is present (optional operation). If this list does not contain
>   the element, it is unchanged. More formally, removes the element with
>   the lowest index i such that (o==null ? get(i)==null :
>   o.equals(get(i))) (if such an element exists). Returns true if this
>   list contained the specified element (or equivalently, if this list
>   changed as a result of the call).

What you need is probably [List.remove(int index)](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/List.html#remove(int)).

Comment: I don't agree with your answer, as I believe OP wants to remove the ticket by object, not by index. For that, the `Ticket` classes `equals` method needs to be overriden.